# css thumb carousel stopping at 0

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

i am working on a thumb slider carousel for my project. 
I did it using css3. what i did is , i used a cover div  and inside that i used a ul and slide it left and right. the cover div overflow is hidden. 
Now it works fine but the problem is, 
i am unable to stop the slide at the end of Li's. 
how can I achieve that? 
I tried the if else statements but i was confused.
Well the full clode with comments is here
**http://jsfiddle.net/pqHAK/**

here is the sample code

```
        $('#thumbsList').css('margin-left', positionToBeMoved + 'px');
```

The full code is in the Fiddle.
Please tell me where am i doing this wrong
thanks.

Comment: Will the no of `li` elements be fixed i.e 30 ? or it'll be dynamic ?

Comment: like  someone can add here. Dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for left ARROW click use this

```
            if (currentPosition!=0) {
                var positionToBeMoved = currentPosition + 77;

                // Setting th Final Fix//
                $('#thumbsList').css('margin-left', positionToBeMoved + 'px');
            } else {


            }
```

then it will stop passing after first div to the left.
But you have to be careful that the moving should stop before you check it

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pqHAK/1/)

Added this condition to check position:

```
$('li').length/2 * 154 - window.innerWidth < positionToBeMoved
```

Which is number of li's divided by 2 minus width of window to calculate position.

You might need to tweak this formula a bit but this should guide you to right direction.

Comment: if id do this  
                if (currentPosition<=0) {
                    alert('you cannot go pass this');
                }
still when i move to next slide and come back it says the same message

Comment: what is window.innerwidth?

Comment: i am still unable to get what ou are trying to say.